# cygwin awk output to windows line delimeters

Tags: awk, cygwin, newlines

I could find the way to print zip entries' list and forward to a txt file.

```
unzip -l my.zip | awk '{print $4}' > my.txt
```

When I open the file `my.txt` in windows' notepad the line delimiters ignored and all lines renders in a single line.

How can I make those piped lines to have appropriate line delimiters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of each `awk` processed line is terminated in a linefeed (`\n`) which is the Unix/Linux standard.  Windows/DOS expects a carriage return followed by a linefeed to mark the end of the line (`\r\n`).  `notepad` will display all Linux generated files as you are currently seeing them.

To resolve, pipe the output of `awk` through the `unix2dos` command, which converts `n`s to `\r\n`s for you:

```
unzip -l my.zip | awk '{print $4}' |unix2dos > my.txt
```

Alternatively, try telling `awk` to output `\r\n` at the end of each line using the `ORS` variable:

```
unzip -l my.zip | awk -v ORS='\r\n' '{print $4}' > my.txt
```

To list without header and footer:

```
unzip -l my.zip | awk -v ORS='\r\n' '{print $4}' | tail -n +4 | head -n -2 > my.txt
```

**Or**

Alternatively, use `zipinfo -1 <zip file>` (number 1, not letter l) to list files without a header and footer. You may still need to pipe it through `unix2dos`. Useful only if `zipinfo` is available in CygWin.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to suppress headers and footers of `unzip -l` command? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to convert the output file's line delimiters to dos style with `unix2dos`.

```
$ unix2dos my.txt
unix2dos: converting file cdc_1.1.jar.txt to DOS format...
```